# Could not bind to the nested BindableProperty

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have created bindable property called Text in TargetClass.cs. That Text property is nested bindable property. TargetClass.cs :

```
public class TargetClass : BindableObject
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("Text", typeof(string), typeof(TargetClass), "Default", BindingMode.TwoWay, null,
                    OnTextChanged);

    private static void OnTextChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {

    }

    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(TextProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have created MyView.cs

```
 public class MyView : ContentView
{
    private TargetClass target;
    Label label;
    public TargetClass Target
    {
        get
        {
            return target;
        }
        set
        {
            target = value;
            label.Text = target.Text;
        }
    }
    public MyView()
    {
        label = new Label();
        label.FontSize = 50;
        Content = label;
    }
}
```

ViewModel.cs :

```
 public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string m_text = "New Value";
    public string TextValue
    {
        get { return m_text; }
        set
        {
            m_text = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TextValue");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml :

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BindingDemo"
         x:Class="BindingDemo.MainPage">

<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <local:ViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<StackLayout>
    <local:MyView >
        <local:MyView.Target>
            <local:TargetClass  Text="{Binding TextValue}" >
            </local:TargetClass>
        </local:MyView.Target>
    </local:MyView>
</StackLayout>
```

It is working when I give some string value to Text property like,

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <local:ViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:TargetClass x:Key="target" Text="Hello World"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
<StackLayout>
    <local:MyView Target="{StaticResource target}"/>
</StackLayout>
```

in xaml.

But it doesnt work in MVVM binding When I bind the Text property like,

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <local:ViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<StackLayout>
    <local:MyView >
        <local:MyView.Target>
            <local:TargetClass  Text="{Binding TextValue}" >
            </local:TargetClass>
        </local:MyView.Target>
    </local:MyView>
    <Button Text="Click" Clicked="Button_Clicked" />
</StackLayout>
```

There is no problem with MVVM binding(ViewModel.cs) because it works well with another bindable property.

But it works if the Text property is added in MyView.cs and used like MyView.Text. It doesn't work only when it is added in TargetClass.cs and used like MyView.TargetClass.Text.

Is it possible to use the nested property in data binding in Xamarin Forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not binding the ViewModel to your binableproperty TargetClass.

**Solution**: Make the TargetClass inherit from ContentPage and then set the BindingContext.

```
 public class TargetClass : ContentPage
{
    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(TextProperty, value);
        }
    }
    public TargetClass()
    {
        this.BindingContext = new ViewModel();
    }
    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("Text", typeof(string), typeof(TargetClass), "Default", BindingMode.TwoWay, null,
                    OnTextChanged);
    private static void OnTextChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        //var control = bindable as TargetClass;
        //control.Text = newValue.ToString();
    }
}
```

[image]